# Tab navigation not working in AngularJS app

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

It's 3:40AM and I'm going to give up trying for tonight.

The tabs will not update the page outside of the navigation area.

The PanelController looks like this:-

```
app.controller('PanelController', function($scope) {

    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.selectTab = function(setTab) {

        $scope.tab = setTab;

    };

    $scope.isSelected = function(checkTab) {

        return $scope.tab === checkTab;

    };

});
```

and the nav pane looks like this:-

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-controller="PanelController">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li ng-class="{ active:isSelected(1) }">
      <a href ng-click="selectTab(1)">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:isSelected(2) }">
      <a href ng-click="selectTab(2)">About{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:isSelected(3) }">
      <a href ng-click="selectTab(3)">Contact</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

and the placeholder HTML for my two tabs is as follows:-

```
    <div ng-controller="PanelController">
      <div ng-show="isSelected(1)">
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="isSelected(2)">
        <p>Please work</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, the {{tab}} next to 'About' in my navbar is updating in my view as I click the tabs, as is the active class. When I place a {{tab}} expression outside of the navbar it isn't updating whenever it's clicked. Obviously this is something related to the scope of the variable, but I am using the PanelController on the parent of both the nav and my main area.

I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I'd appreciate a fresh pair of eyes -- I've already some help with this already and any more will be graciously accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem diagnosis  is fairly simple, 2 controllers means 2 instances that each have their own scope

You would need to use a service or events to have them communicate together

Comment: Thanks -- I just realised that when I use the 'ng-controller' attribute it was creating a different instance of the panelcontroller each time, which doesn share the data. Either way, my second controller only deals with one particular thing which shouldn't need to do anything in the other.

I put the panel ctrl tag in the body and now it's working!